# Assignment to non-void functions (returning nothing) can change the values?

Tags: c++

I encountered this problem in my program which was creating problems. so let me explain it by a example:

```
#include<iostream>

int func(){
        if(1==0) return 100;
}

int main(){

        int x=99;
        x= func();
        std::cout<<"Value of x: " << x <<std::endl;
}
```

I had thought the output will be `99` but output is `0`, so what's going on here?

Comment: i hate und. behavior , thank you friends :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *undefined behavior* because your function is declared to return an `int` but the execution path through the function never reaches a `return` statement.

In C++ it is illegal to exit a function defined as returning a non-`void` type other than via a return statement with an argument.

ISO/IEC 14882:2003 6.6.3 [stmt.return] / 2:

> [...] Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

Answer (score 4):

It is causing undefined behavior. The condition is false so there is no return value from the function.

Answer (score 2):

From C++03 6.6.3/2 "The return statement":

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

Since your function flows "off the end", it's UB and you can expect nothing (or anything).

As a side note: this is slightly different than in C, where flowing off the end of a function that is declared to return something is *not* UB in itself - it becomes UB only if the caller *uses* the result of a function that does that.

In other words, using your example, in C++ you have UB at the moment `func()` returns, whether that result is assigned to `x` or not. In C it's UB only because you assign the result to `x`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the compiler you are using.

When you compile this code, a normal compiler will cause a warning similar to:

> warning C4715: 'func' : not all control paths return a value

It looks like your compiler is placing a statement that returns `0` when it doesn't find a `return` statement on the way out.  So, `x` will be assigned `0`.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has said, you have undefined behavior. As for how to fix/identify it, one way would be to use warning flags when compiling your program. If you run your code in codepad, it's easy to see the issue:

http://codepad.org/MXDSniWw

```
cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
In function 'int func()':
Line 5: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

In `func()`, your if loop is never true, but you haven't specified any other return value, so you have undefined behavior. Adding `return 0;` after the `if..` will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So you expect a 99, the safest bet is to pass x by reference:

```
#include<iostream>

void func(int& a){
    if (1==0)
        a = 100;
}

int main(){
    int x(99);
    func(x);
    std::cout << "Value of x: " << x << std::endl;
}
```